# SharePoint what is `sender` and `args`?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am slowly learning JavaScript in conjunction with SharePoint. The following code works fine but I do not understand what the `sender` and `args` are in the `onCourseCodeSucceeded` and `onCourseCodeQueryFailed` functions.

```
// Add data to the courseCode Control   


function retrieveCourseCodes() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Course List');
            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
                '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>');
            this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.load(collListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCourseCodeSucceeded), 
                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCourseCodeQueryFailed));        
        }

        function onCourseCodeSucceeded(sender, args) {
            var listItemInfo = '';
            var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
            var courseCodes = document.getElementById('classCourseCodes');
            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                var courseOption = document.createElement('option');
                courseOption.value = oListItem.get_item('Title');
                courseOption.text = oListItem.get_item('Title');
                courseCodes.add(courseOption)
            }
        }

        function onCourseCodeQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
```

Comment: what is `Function.createDelegate` - oh, I see ... read [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393582.aspx)

Comment: note, sender/args is what those functions are called with by `.executeQueryAsync` - see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907.aspx)

Comment: @JaromandaX I appreciate the input. The recommended documention does not seem to explain what the `sender` and `args` are or what they are used for.

Comment: Indeed, Microsoft's documentation is very poor, isn't it!! Try `console.log(sender, args)` - see if you can make sense of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these parameters are supplied by the Javascript Client Object Model when the javascript functions are executed after the call to SharePoint is made.

Sender parameter is as instance of the class ClientRequest class. 
You can use get_webRequest method of ClientRequest class to get the object used to call the SharePoint.

The args parameter is an instance of the ClientRequestFailedEventArgs/ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs class. 
This class has a get_request method that returns the same object return by the get_webRequest method of the class ClientRequest.

Refer this link for brief description. This is the best description I have found so far for this topic..

https://books.google.co.in/books?id=KLcd3spuSwMC&pg=PA415&lpg=PA415&dq=sender+and+args+in+javascript&source=bl&ots=XJkUVOBOrS&sig=uJ2Ta3Xcy6jfstxP9yDJWUXN_2I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP87OXoqzYAhWMQo8KHQwuDbMQ6AEIbTAH#v=onepage&q=sender%20and%20args%20in%20javascript&f=false

Comment: So is it possible to pass additional values to the `onSucceded` function?

Comment: Refer this link to pass parameters to success function. -- https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/640901/Passing-parameters-to-Success-method-in-executeQue